# Is it possible to nest controllers/have controllers as inner classes in Spring 4 MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

I want to have a controller that maps to `/site/` and within that two different controllers to look something like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/api")
public class ApiController {
    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/foo")
    public class FooController {
        //Some /foo/* methods here
    }

    @Controller
    @RequestMapping(value="/bar")
    public class BarController {
       //Some /bar/* methods here
    }

    //Other methods that don't match /foo or /bar
}
```

Is this okay or would be it be better practice to split it up into two separate controllers with `/site/foo` and `/site/bar` mappings?

Comment: Why do you need inner one as class? Why can't simply use method?

Comment: It's okay. Depends on how functionally-related foo and bar are.  If they're almost the same, this is reasonable.  Usually they're not the same, so this wouldn't be a good design.

Comment: @PaulHicks: That's what I thought, thank you for the confirmation.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Tying your class hierarchy to your resource hierarchy should not be the main design driver here.

IN Spring MVC, Controllers are simple POJOs to make them easy to test, composition is favored over inheritance, annotations are used to convey meaning and make your code more readable.

Nesting Controllers under Controllers defeats several of those goals.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Seems like Paulin was asking whether or not it is possible — I, too, am interested in if it can be done since most of my tests have proven otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

You should be using methods and not classes for the mappings. The code should be written like this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/site")
public class ApiController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/foo", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doFoo {
        // Foo Logic
        return "Running Foo";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/bar", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String doBar {
        // Bar Logic
        return "Running Bar";
    }
}
```

Comment: `FooController` and `BarController` will be controllers in their own rights, with their own methods. The parent controller would be a meta controller of sorts.