# Nested @RestController (inner class) - any side effects?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a class annotated with @RestController. Inside that class I have an inner class, which is again annotated with @RestController. Is this fine or are there any unintended side-effects with regards bean creation (using Spring)?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/internal")
public class ClientController {

    @GetMapping("/clients/{id}")
    public ClientDTO.OutDetail findOne(@PathVariable String id) {
        return clientService.findOne(id, ClientDTO.OutDetail.class);
    }

    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/api/v1/external")
    public class ExternalApi {

        @GetMapping("/clients/{id}")
        public ClientDTO.OutDetailExt findOne(@PathVariable String id) {
            return clientService.findOne(id, ClientDTO.OutDetailExt.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056787/is-it-possible-to-nest-controllers-have-controllers-as-inner-classes-in-spring-4. But again this is not good design and you since ExternalApi is anyways a public class, it must be seperated into another class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. First remove `public` from inner class and now your URL will be `http://ip:port/appName/api/v1/external/clients/{id}`. But my suggestion is that please create different RestController class so you can easily track it.