# use three-level url in spring controller - kotlin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I want to use multiple hierarchical url

so i can use class-level RequestMapping and method-level Mapping

but controller has 6-methods, and 4 of 6 has same url

in this reason, i want middle-level url mapping
for grouping 4-methods

I tried like this

```
@RequestMapping("level1")
class Controller{
  @RequestMapping("level2")
  inner class InnerController{
    @GetMapping("level3")
    fun method(){}
  }
}
```

but it seems not work

middle-level mapping is possible in spring?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to nest controllers/have controllers as inner classes in Spring 4 MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056787/is-it-possible-to-nest-controllers-have-controllers-as-inner-classes-in-spring-4)

Comment: @Haridarshan
seems like, i tried like that, but it was not too keen on the idea, so I'm wondering if there's another method or if it's even possible.